# Deploying a .net project to development server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, app-config

I developed a winforms app locally on my machine. It reads data from a csv file and looks up related information from a database (by executing a stored proc).

I moved that to the development server and tried running it, but I get an error when at the line that gets SQL connection string from app.config file. The error is: **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**. Of course the app runs fine on my machine.

I commented out all lines following this code, and the error message is displayed. I am guessing it has to do with the conn.ConnectionString line.

The SQL database is pointing to the correct db server & UID & pwd are correct.  What would be causing the error?

```
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SilverTicker"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Write a simple application that just connects to the database and put it on the development server. If this fails, you may not have access to the database server via your dev server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the objects in your code sample is returning "null". I'm guessing that it's

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SilverTicker"].ConnectionString
```

Put a breakpoint on that line and check the contents of the `.ConnectionStrings` collection to be sure that it contains "SilverTicker".

I'm guessing that `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SilverTicket"]` is undefined (probably because of an inconsistency between `app.config` in the two environments), so accessing it's `.ConnectionString` property is throwing an exception.

Comment: solution was to create the connectionstring using the settings.settings interface. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user1111955 (may I call you user9?) .settings and app.config are pretty equivalent. I'm still betting that you either didn't deploy, or deployed the wrong version of, app.config with your app. It doesn't get compiled in; you have to deploy it.

Answer (score 1):

Check its retriving data or not

if you have written like

```
DataSet.Table[0]
```

check tis returning data and DataSet must contain table in it .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't need the second .connectionstring. You have to put the connection string in the right place in the connectionstrings tag in the app.config. The place needs to be specific in the app.config otherwise your code won't find the connection string.